# Parsing C++ Command-Line Arguments

Tags: c++, argv

Is there some way to do this?
If i have input like this: `test "1"2 3` then i want `argv[0]=test`, `argv[1]=1`, `argv[2]=2`, `argv[3]=3`. But i have `argv[1]=12` and `argv[2]=3`.

Comment: remove "" from "1". just pass *test 1 2 3*.

Comment: Arguments are delimited by whitespace. Wouldn't it be easier just to fix the input arguments?

Comment: This isn't a C++ issue, it's a shell issue.  It's the shell that decides how to interpret what you type and convert it to arguments.

Comment: It depends on the OS and shell. Command line argument processing is not OS-independent, except for the most simple. Typically, in Unix-land the quotes are removed by the shell, which leaves you no information about the original, while in Windows they're passed to the process.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: In Windows the process creation doesn't even support passing individual arguments to the new process. So in general it's not the case that "It's the shell that decides how to interpret what you type and convert it to arguments". However, that's close to reality in Unix-land.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I know nothing about Windows!  However, in which case, how do command-line arguments (in Windows) get from the command-line to the process?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: It (whatever the parent process defines as command line) is passed as a single string to `CreateProcess` API func. It can then be accessed by the process via `GetCommandLine`, and  a default parsing (which incidentally removes quotes, but the rules are so horribly complicated that apparently no-one can specify them exactly) via `CommandLineToArgvW`. On top the runtime library provides its own parsing, which with the compilers I have used can be overridden. Example of using the two API functions in my answer below. Accessing command line of other process = a bit intricate. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove a quotations and call a program with

```
./test 1 2 3
```

You will find 1, 2, 3 in argv[1], argv[2] and argv[3] respectively.

Comment: I know it, i just thought there is some way to do it without space between arguments.

Comment: @user3572950 of course there is: pass ./test 1_2_3 and parse/split elements with _ as separator

Answer (score 1):

You have to use space after " and before 2 because space is parameters separator

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the literal question,

> **”** Is there some way to do this? If i have input like this: `test "1"2 3` then i want `argv[0]=test`, `argv[1]=1`, `argv[2]=2`, `argv[3]=3`

it’s technically possible to do with any shell and OS combination where the quotes are passed on to the process.

That includes in particular Windows.

```
// Windows-specific code.
#undef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#include <windows.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

auto wide_main( int argc, wchar_t const* const* const argv )
    -> int
{
    using std::wcout; using std::endl;

    wcout << "[" << ::GetCommandLine() << "]" << endl;  
    wcout << argc << " command line argument(s):" << endl;
    for( int i = 0; i < argc; ++i )
    {
        wcout << "  " << i << ": [" << argv[i] << "]" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

static void local_free( wchar_t** p ) { ::LocalFree( p ); }

auto main()
    -> int
{
    using std::unique_ptr;

    int n_args = 0;
    wchar_t** const raw_p_args = ::CommandLineToArgvW(
        ::GetCommandLine(), &n_args
        );
    if( raw_p_args == nullptr ) { return E_FAIL; }
    try
    {
        unique_ptr<wchar_t*, void(*)(wchar_t**)> const p_args(
            raw_p_args, &local_free
            );
        return wide_main( n_args, raw_p_args );
    }
    catch( ... )
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Example test:

```
[H:\dev\test\0112]
> foo 1 "2"3
[foo  1 "2"3]                      ← You have access to the quotes.
3 command line argument(s):
  0: [foo]
  1: [1]
  2: [23]

[H:\dev\test\0112]
> _
```

So technically all you need to do, in Windows, using one of the standard Windows command  interpreters, is to implement your own **command line parsing**.

That is however too large a topic to treat in an answer.

The practical upshot is, just invoke your program like `foo 1 2 3` instead of `foo 1 "2"3`.